# SQL table transformation - columns stat

Tags: sql, t-sql, grouping, transformation, aggregation

Let's imagine view:

[image]

and I would like to transform it in elegant way, to something like the following:

[image]

I am doing it with use following query:

```
SELECT empid,
    sum(CASE WHEN YEAR(ordermonth) = '2014' THEN val END) '2014',
    sum(CASE WHEN YEAR(ordermonth) = '2015' THEN val END) '2015',
    sum(CASE WHEN YEAR(ordermonth) = '2016' THEN val END) '2016'
FROM Sales.EmpOrders
GROUP BY empid;
```

Question is: what smart mechanism can I use to avoid listing cases manually, if there are many of them?

Comment: You would have to use dynamic SQL, and the code would be much messier.

Comment: I heard that using CTE, joining operation and maybe pivot it is possible, but I can be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If yo need to go DYNAMIC

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(Year(ordermonth)) From sales.emporders  Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
Select [empid],' + @SQL + '
From (
        Select empid
              ,item  = year(ordermonth)
              ,value = val
         From sales.emporders A
     ) A
 Pivot (sum(value) For [item] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Comment: This would faster with a `years` table to join on instead of using `year()`, but that might be too much to ask. Something like this: http://rextester.com/UHUV4630

Comment: @SqlZim Agreed, but Year() is a fast calc.  That said, I do prefer conditional aggregations as you demonstrated.  I just didn't want to write the dynamic sql for conditional aggregations.  The syntax above is easy to digest and support.

Comment: I was a little sloppy with my rextester and didn't make the dates `not null`, I updated it to fix that. -- That said, the row size is only 8 bytes, so you could fit 1000 years in this table and it would still only take up 1 data page (just shy of 8kb). I have found it to perform quite well.

Comment: I know you're a fan of benchmarks, this is a particularly persuasive set of them: [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 3 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer your question, but you could make your query more efficient by not using the `year()` function:

```
select empid,
    sum(case when ordermonth >= '20140101' and ordermonth < '20150101' then val end) '2014',
    sum(case when ordermonth >= '20150101' and ordermonth < '20160101' then val end) '2015',
    sum(case when ordermonth >= '20160101' and ordermonth < '20170101' then val end) '2016'
from sales.emporders
group by empid;
```